# How to create a map of key:array in shell?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I want to create map in shell. Where each value is an array. So the map is key:array pair. For example it can be like this :

```
"Key1" : a1 a2 a3 a4
"key2" : b1 b2 b3
"key3" : c1
```

basically my code looks like this

```
listService(){
serviceType=$1
servicesList=($(getServices $serviceType))
}

listService serviceTypeA
listService serviceTypeB
listService serviceTypeC
```

here `getServices` is a function which returns an array of services based on the argument passed as `$serviceType`. So every time i call the `listService` function my `serviceList` gets overridden by new service list. But I want to keep all the services from different service type in form of a map like this :

```
"serviceA" : a1 a2 a3 a4
"serviceB" : b1 b2 b3
"serviceC" : c1
```

After that I want to access each array based on the key. How to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : I tried the answer provided by @cdarke . Here is my code now :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A arrayMap

getValues(){
  key=$1
  case $key in
    AAA )
    arr=( AA AAA AAAA )
      ;;
    BBB )
    arr=( BB BB BBBB )
      ;;
    CCC )
    arr=()
    ;;
    esac
    echo "${arr[@]}"
}

fillArrayMap(){
  param=$1
  values=( $(getValues $param) )
  printf "\nIn $param\n"
  echo -e "\nArray values is: ${values[@]}\n"
  printf "\nLength of the array values is : ${#values[@]}\n"
  arrayMap["$param"]=$values #THIS IS THE KEY LINE
  valuesList=${arrayMap[$param]} 
  echo -e "\nArray valuesList is: ${valuesList[@]}\n"
  printf "\nLength of the array valuesList is : ${#valuesList[@]}\n"
}

fillArrayMap AAA
fillArrayMap BBB
fillArrayMap CCC
```

Now from output I can see `valuesList` is getting only the first element of the `values` array. But I want `valuesList` to contain all the elements returned by the method `getValues`. i.e

```
valuesList= ${arrayMap[$param]}
```

now `valuesList` should contain all the elements, instead now it contains only 1 element. How to fix that ?

Note: My goal is to access each individual element like AAA or AA, I don't need it as a whole as a string like AA AAA AAAA

Comment: gawk has 2-d array, (in fact it was impl. by hastable), you can consider to use awk if your other logic could be dragged in.

Comment: or do your job in python. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays, but I don't think you need one.  You can store a string in the form of a list in an array element, which will give you what you ask for.

```
# My made-up version of getServices
getServices() {
    nm="$1"
    last=${nm##*Type}
    retn=(${last}1 ${last}2 ${last}3 ${last}4)
    echo "${retn[@]}"
}


declare -A serviceList
listService(){
    serviceType="$1"

    # Here I use the key to make an assignment, which adds to the hash
    serviceList["$serviceType"]=$(getServices $serviceType) 
}

listService serviceTypeA
listService serviceTypeB
listService serviceTypeC

for key in ${!serviceList[@]}
do
    echo "\"$key\": ${serviceList[$key]}"
done
```

Gives:

```
"serviceTypeC": C1 C2 C3 C4
"serviceTypeB": B1 B2 B3 B4
"serviceTypeA": A1 A2 A3 A4
```

EDIT for new question:

alter:

```
arrayMap["$param"]=$values     # THIS IS THE KEY LINE
valuesList=${arrayMap[$param]}
```

to:

```
arrayMap["$param"]=${values[@]} 
valuesList=( ${arrayMap[$param]}  )
```

When you refer to an array variable by just it's name (`$values`) you only get **the first element**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and encountered another issue. Added same in the question details. can you please suggest anything @cdarke ?

Answer (score 4):

As cdarke already mentioned, bash arrays are one-dimensional. Over the years, folks have come up with ways to "fake" multi-dimensional arrays.

Two methods I've used are to maintain *an array of array descriptions*, or *an array of pointers to other arrays*. I'll answer with the former; the latter should be obvious if you want to explore on your own.

Here's a minimal example of array content getting used to populate variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A a=(
  [b]='([0]="one" [1]="two")'
  [c]='([0]="three" [1]="four")'
)

declare -p a

for key in ${!a[@]}; do
  declare -a $key="${a[$key]}"
  declare -p $key
done
```

Produces:

```
declare -A a=([b]="([0]=\"one\" [1]=\"two\")" [c]="([0]=\"three\" [1]=\"four\")" )
declare -a b=([0]="one" [1]="two")
declare -a c=([0]="three" [1]="four")
```

The critical bit here is that you're using `declare` to refer to the value of `$key`, since you can't just say `$var="value"` in bash.

Of course, you don't need to name your variables for the value of `$key` if you don't want to. Storing values in, say `$value`, would free you up to use special characters in `$key`.

An even simpler alternative, if it doesn't offend your sensibilities or restrict your key names too much, is to store the entire output of a `declare -p` command in the value of the array, and then `eval` it when you need it. For example:

```
declare -A a=(
 [b]='declare -a b=([0]="one" [1]="two")'
 [c]='declare -a c=([0]="three" [1]="four")'
)

for key in ${!a[@]}; do
  eval "${a[$key]}"
done
```

[Some people don't like `eval`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) :-)  It remains, however in your toolbox.

In your case, it's a little hard to advise because you haven't provided a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but here's my contrived example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# contrived getServices function, since you didn't provide one
getServices() {
    local -a value=()
    local last="${1:$((${#1}-1)):1}"   # last character of $1
    for n in $( seq 1 $(( $RANDOM / 8192 + 1 )) ); do
      value+=(${last}${n})
    done
    declare -p value     # output of this function is actual bash code.
}

# populate the array
listService() {
    servicesList[$1]=$( getServices $1 )
}

# Initialize this as empty to make `eval` safer
declare -A servicesList=()

# These services seem interesting.
listService serviceA
listService serviceB
listService serviceC

# Note that we're stepping through KEYS here, not values.
for row in "${!servicesList[@]}"; do
    printf '"%s": ' "$row"
    eval "${servicesList[$row]}"   # Someone is bound to complain about this.
    for column in "${!value[@]}"; do
        # Add whatever $row and $column specific code you like here.
        printf '%s ' "${value[$column]}"
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

My output:

```
$ bash 2dimarrayexample
"serviceC": C1
"serviceB": B1 B2 B3 B4
"serviceA": A1 A2
```

Of course, your output may differ, since getServices produces random output. :)

Comment: Why is the output in a different order than the order in which you ran `listService`? Also, what's the risk associated with using `eval` this way? Must be very subtle, I don't see it at all.

Comment: @Graham - associative arrays are not kept in order in bash. If you need to keep order, you could maintain a separate non-associative (numbered) array pointing to the keys in the associative array, then step through the second array with a `for` loop to guarantee your order.